# PHP Regex: How do I replace all occurrences of a word starting with a colon?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to replace all the `:first_name` occurrences in my `$body` variable with `$first_name` but i'm stuck with the regex part. The regex isn't working. When I echo the body the original string gets printed. What's the correct regex?

```
$first_name = "Joe";
$body = "Hi :first_name. Have a nice day :first_name!";
$regex = "/\b:first_name\b/";
$body = preg_replace($regex, $first_name, $body);
echo $body;
```

Comment: looks like you want to do some templateing, strongly recommend not reinventing the wheel and look at the existing options

Comment: `\b` does not match in between a space and `:`.

Comment: `/\:first_name/`.

Comment: ^:(.*)  --> https://regex101.com/r/Jo6fM1/1

Comment: Why does it have to be regex? This is pretty straight forward `str_replace`.

Comment: use str_replace(':first_name',$first_name,$body);

Comment: If you use something like `$array[':first_name'] = "Joe";` then the `str_replace` is even cooler and more extensible.

Comment: is this database/PDO related? the colon suggests this, being a named placeholder. Rather odd to see why you need to do what you're asking.

Comment: @AbraCadaver how would I do that?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner no its not db. I have a string email template and need to replace the words starting with a colon

Comment: @altoids Ok, I had to make sure. Had it been that, there would have probably been another way to do this, but I see you found your solution, *cheers*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you asked in the comments, this is more extensible and should be easier.  Use `str_replace` and an array:

```
$array[':first_name'] = "Joe";
$array[':last_name'] = "Smith";

$body = str_replace(array_keys($array), $array, $body);
```

Another alternative with `strtr`:

```
$body = strtr($body, $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**: `:\w+` or `:first_name`

```
$first_name = "Joe";
$text = "Hi :first_name. Have a nice day :first_name!";

$text = preg_replace('/:(\w+)/', $first_name, $text);

print_r($text);
```

**Output**:

```
Hi Joe. Have a nice day Joe!
```

Comment: OP wants `Joe` not `$first_name`.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard I missed that. Updated!